# Branch.io custom event count not increasing for quick links

Tags: branch.io

I have created a quick link from https://dashboard.branch.io/quick-links. When the user opens the link and tries to register the account on our website, a custom event is triggered from server side (Java) using the branch http API.

I can see that event in the **Liveview** section of Branch.io dashboard. But, when I go to the quicks section, the count for my custom event column is always showing as 0.

Is there any specific Branch related parameter that I need to send from client side (browser) to server side while submitting the form, to let Branch know that the custom event should be linked to a specific link, so I can see the custom event count increasing for that link in quick links section.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom event will not be attributed to your link click if you trigger the event on the server side.

You should trigger the custom event from the client side post registration. You can put this in the callback of your registration method. If you navigate away from the initial redirect to your webpage, make sure that page has the Branch Web SDK initialized, and that you have the _branch_match_id(found in the address bar of your redirect) appended to your web url. This _branch_match_id is what Branch uses to attribute the custom event to your link click.

https://docs.branch.io/pages/web/integrate/#track-events

Comment: I totally understand what you said. But, the problem is that after successful registration, we redirect back to the url from where the user came from using server side redirect. The url where user is redirected is not under our control. One option I'm thinking of is to use ajax call to register user, then publish event and finally redirect the user.